# Python - Override a staticmethod

Tags: python

How do I override a staticmethod and keep it static?

```
In [6]: class Foo(object):
   ...:     @staticmethod
   ...:     def foo(a, b):
   ...:         print a + b
   ...:         
   ...:         

In [7]: Foo.foo
Out[7]: <function foo at 0x86a1a74>

In [8]: class Bar(Foo):
   ...:     def foo(a, b):
   ...:         print a - b
   ...:         
   ...:         

In [9]: Bar.foo
Out[9]: <unbound method Bar.foo>
```

I've tried decorated Bar's foo with staticmethod and it works. But I have to decorated it everytime I subclass.

Comment: That's just the way it works. You could make some horrible hack with metaclasses to get the behavior you want, but I would strongly recommend against it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's how you are supposed to do it. In other programming languages you have to use the `static` keyword everytime, too.

Answer (score 0):

There’s no way to force subclasses to implement methods as a specific kind of method. Not only that but you can even change the signature of an inherited method when implementing it in a subclass in any way you like and it will work:

```
>>> class Foo:
...     @staticmethod
...     def foo(a, b):
...         print(a + b)
...
>>> class Bar(Foo):
...     @staticmethod
...     def foo(*args):
...         print(sum(args))
...
>>> Bar().foo(*range(10))
45
```